# Obtaining the number of correct messages in the network layer by the Omnet++ result collection

Tags: omnet++

Suppose in a wireless network with 25 nodes, we have a scenario where some of each node sends messages to some other nodes according to a routing protocol such as AODV.
We simulate this network. After finishing the simulation, how to obtain the number of correct messages on the network layer by the Omnet++ result collection? Two metrics are defined, sentPacketCount and receivedPacketCount.
By correct messages, I mean messages received by a node whose destination address field is the address of the same node. If retransmission occurs, it should be counted once for the receiver side for receivedPacketCount, in fact, received Packet Count will be increased when the packet is received in destination node. Every packet is sent, sentPacketCount will be increased.
If a node has more than an application, all the messages generated by all applications of the same node must be counted.

A part of omnetpp.ini file is for a node:

```
*.hostA.numApps = 2
*.hostA.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.hostA.app[0].destAddresses = "hostB"
*.hostA.app[0].destPort = 5000
*.hostA.app[0].messageLength = 1000B
*.hostA.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
*.hostA.app[0].packetName = "UDPData"

*.hostA.app[0].typename = "TcpBasicApp"
*.hostA.app[0].destAddresses = "hostC"
*.hostA.app[0].destPort = 5001
*.hostA.app[0].messageLength = 1024B
*.hostA.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(45ms)
*.hostA.app[0].packetName = "TCPData"
```

Comment: You should specify, what do you mean by packet? On what OSI level you want to count the packets? On transport layer, network layer and on link layer, packets could be fragmented or defragmented so their size and number can be vastly different. Also on a wireless channel if there is a retransmission, does it count twice or just once? Or are you just interested in the number of dropped packets at link layer level?

Comment: According @Rudi's comment, I modify the question for more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `TcpBasicApp` or any other TCP app, the count of packets is meaningless. Tcp apps have streams, not packets. Even if you send out 1000 bytes in one write operation to a TCP socket, the other end may get it using 3 read operation, or 20... TCP also guarantees the delivery of the packets, so *number of successfully sent packets = number of successfully received packets*. So byte count statistics also do not matter.

Number of sent/received packets/bytes makes sense for UDP traffic. In UDP there is a concept of packets and there is no guaranteed delivery. Luckily `UdpBasicApp` gathers these statistics by default. Take a look at the [packetReceived](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.ned#L66) and `packetSent` statistic. It gathers both packet count and total byte count.

You may need to turn on scalar recording on all apps:

```
**.app[*].*.scalar-recording = true
```